# How to recognize and type in search bar with selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to type in the search bar as seen in the picture in Sprouts. I've tried many different iterations but cannot type in the search bar. What am i doing wrong?

[image]

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
website = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/myPath/chromedriver',options = options)
sprouts         = {"url" : "https://shop.sprouts.com/"}
website.get(sprouts['url'])

search_bar = website.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"css-4hd4ug")
search_bar.send_keys("bananas")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: I deleted my answer and then undeleted it, so you might not see it in your inbox, hence this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the syntax for selecting a class would be using a dot (.) before the class name, so:

```
.css-4hd4ug
```

second, there are multiple of that class, so, instead I'd go for this CSS selector copied straight from chrome `#sticky-react-header > div > div.css-q1n3l > div.css-c1jgn7 > form > div > input`.

Third, it takes time for the element to appear, so you should use `presence_of_element_located`. See: *[Selenium - wait until element is present, visible and interactable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable)*

```
search_bar = WebDriverWait(website, 20).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#sticky-react-header > div > div.css-q1n3l > div.css-c1jgn7 > form > div > input"))
)
```

Using your code, it should be refactored to:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
website = webdriver.Chrome()
sprouts = {"url": "https://shop.sprouts.com/"}
website.get(sprouts["url"])


search_bar = WebDriverWait(website, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (
            By.CSS_SELECTOR,
            "#sticky-react-header > div > div.css-q1n3l > div.css-c1jgn7 > form > div > input",
        )
    )
)


search_bar.click()
search_bar.send_keys("bananas")
```

Comment: Your answer was also correct; i gave it to you as you gave slightly more info. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can enter the value in Search bar using the below XPATH:

```
search_bar = website.find_element(By.XPATH,".//*[@class='css-1nxa74h']/input")
```

Or using the below CSS_SELECTOR:

```
search_bar = website.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".css-1nxa74h input")
```

Comment: Your answer was correct!! Thank you.